# Does convergence in $L^1$ of $\{f_n(\cdot,\ell)\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ for each $\ell \in \mathbb{Q}$ implies convergence for $\ell \in \mathbb{R}$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, probability, convergence-divergence

On a measure space $(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$,
consider a sequence of functions $\{f_n:X \times \mathbb{R} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ with $\ell \in \mathbb{R} \longmapsto f_n(x,\ell)\in \mathbb{R}$ is increasing and continuous for each $x \in X$, $n \in \mathbb{N}$, such that
$$
    \lim_{n \to \infty}\int_X|f_n(x,\ell) - f_0(x,\ell)|\mu(dx) = 0,
   ~\mbox{for all}~
   \ell \in \mathbb{Q},
$$
then does it hold that
$$
    \lim_{n \to \infty}\int_X|f_n(x,\ell) - f_0(x,\ell)|\mu(dx) = 0,
   ~\mbox{for all}~
   \ell \in \mathbb{R}.
$$

My attempt:
if $\mu$ is a finite measure, then for $\ell \in \mathbb{Q}$, $f_n(\cdot,\ell)$ converges to $f_0(\cdot,\ell)$ in measure $\mu$, then it is equivalent to that for any subsequence $\{n_k\}_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ of $\{n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$, there exists a subsubsequence $\{n_{k_m}\}_{m \in \mathbb{N}}$ such that for $\ell \in \mathbb{Q}$, $f_{n_{k_m}}(\cdot,\ell)$ converges to $f_0(\cdot,\ell)$ $\mu$-a.e.

Then we can easily deduce that for $\ell \in \mathbb{R}$, $f_{n_{k_m}}(\cdot,\ell)$ converges to $f_0(\cdot,\ell)$ $\mu$-a.e., which is equivalent to that for $\ell \in \mathbb{R}$, $f_n(\cdot,\ell)$ converges to $f_0(\cdot,\ell)$ in measure $\mu$.
Then it remains to prove that for all $\ell \in \mathbb{R}$, $\{f_n(\cdot,\ell)\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is uniformly integrable.

From another point of view, if we define a projection
\begin{align}
    \pi: (L^1(\mu))^{\mathbb{R}} & \longrightarrow (L^1(\mu))^{\mathbb{Q}},
\\       (f(\cdot,\ell))_{\ell \in \mathbb{R}}  & \longmapsto  (f(\cdot,\ell))_{\ell \in \mathbb{Q}},
\end{align}
and let $E \subset (L^1(\mu))^{\mathbb{R}}$ defined as
$$
        E := \{(f(\cdot,\ell))_{\ell \in \mathbb{R}}: \ell \in \mathbb{R} \longmapsto f(x,\ell)\in \mathbb{R}~\mbox{is increasing and continuous for each}~ x \in X \},
$$
All product spaces are equipped with the product topology and then
I can show that $\pi|_{E}$ is a continuous injective function, the question falls into that is $\pi^{-1}|_{\pi(E)}$ continuous, i.e. is $\pi|_{E}$ a homeomorphism?

Comment: This falls into the question of "can we interchange the limits?" Letting $\ell_0\in\mathbb R\setminus \mathbb Q$, you are asking whether you can interchange the limits $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\lim_{\ell\to \ell_0}.$$ Usually you need the inner limit to have some uniformity to do something like this (and indeed it seems that uniformity is exactly what you are looking for).

Comment: The question is that there is no uniformity, which makes the question interesting and forces us to look a bit deep into the question.

Comment: My attempt already shows that under a finite measure $\mu$, only uniformly integrable for each $\ell$ is needed, which has nothing to do with the uniformity.

Comment: Is $0 \in \Bbb{N}$, i.e., do we know that the monotonicity and continuity also hold for $f_0$?

Comment: Yes. Of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a finite measure $\mu$, since we have
$f_n(\cdot,\ell)$ converges to $f_0(\cdot,\ell)$ in measure for all $\ell \in \mathbb{R}$, we can also give the convergence of $\int_Xf_n(x,\ell)\mu(dx)$ to $\int_Xf_0(x,\ell)\mu(dx)$ for all $\ell \in \mathbb{R}$ by Squeeze theorem.

Fix some $\ell \in \mathbb{R}$, the above two convergence results hold for $\{f_n(x,\ell) - f_n(x,\ell_0)\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$, for some $\ell_0 \in \mathbb{Q}$ and $\ell_0 \le \ell$.

Now by Theorem 21 in Probability and potential A, we know that $\{f_n(x,\ell) - f_n(x,\ell_0)\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is uniformly integrable and hence we can get the convergence in $L^1$ of $f_n(x,\ell) - f_n(x,\ell_0)$ to $f_0(x,\ell) - f_0(x,\ell_0)$.

Finally, the conclusion is obvious.

For $\mu$ is infinite, the argument still works, since we don't really need convergence in measure, what we need is that every subsequence admits a convergent almost surely subsubsequence.